# external css not working while internal does

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

So i'm using the jquery-ui accordion widget and I wanted to adjust the width. When I internally style the  for it, it works. but when i do it externally it doesn't. If someone could help me understand why it doesnt work externally, that would be nice. Also, if someone could help me vertically center the widget, it'd be the best christmas ever. code is below:

HTML (with internal CSS that works):

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="accordion" style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto;">
             ..headers and divs for panels and content
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

external CSS that doesn't work:

```
#accordion {
   width: 500px;
   margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: should work fine, please create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: As for your Christmas present on vertically aligning <div>, refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css

Comment: @charlietfl I just made one but it seemed be working fine there but not on my computer.

Comment: Check the paths to the external CSS file. If things work inline, but not as externals, the path or file name is usually incorrect.

Comment: inspect the rules that apply to element in browser console...can see all rules for any element and order they apply and source of each rule

Comment: so far only thing still working is inline style

Comment: @MunkeyD913 see my updated answer. It might help you find the source of the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Internal (inline) CSS rules have a higher priority than external ones.

There are probably some rules that overriding your external CSS, while the internal gets the max priority and overrides them.

You can check which rule takes place with the "Inspect element" (On chrome - this tool also exist on Firefox, IE etc - just click F12 to open it). When you're inspecting an element you can see which rule is selected and where it appears in the code (file and line number) and also see the whole inheritance tree.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The order of the includes (link elements) plays a role in priorities.

Code lower in the includes or included files has a higher priority. Inline styles in turn have a higher priority than in CSS defined rules.

Then there's the `!important` keyword you can append to make something higher priority.

Priorities are as follows:

1. Inline style with `!important`
2. Stylesheet style with `!important`
3. Inline style without `!important`
4. Stylesheet style without `!important`

Comment: i just tried @mofasa suggestion without any inline style and added !important to the external and it still didn't work. Good to know the priority list though. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery-UI has some default CSS that is overriding your external css. You can gain higher priority than the default CSS by being more exact when specifying elements:

```
body .container #accordion {
   width: 500px;
   margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys. Rookie mistake.

I had two copies of the css file I was using and the html was linked to the one I wasn't editing. Thanks for all the responses though. Got some good tips and info.